# Automatically execute commands on launching python shell

Tags: python, shell

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically run commands on entering the python shell as you would with the .bash_profile or .profile scripts with bash. I would like to automatically import some modules so I don't have to type the whole shebang everytime I hop into the shell.

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup you can use the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable to do this as outlined [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file)

Comment: I don't find that link useful today (14 years later) but a good explanation today is at http://witkowskibartosz.com/blog/pythonstartup_what_it_is_and_how_to_use_it.html

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) if you're doing a lot of interactive work. Your options for this kind of automation expand significantly.