# Alternative to the Chevron Prompt?

Tags: python

I read an article about a month ago about a couple of methods you could throw in you `sitecustomize.py` file to keep track of some different activities as you typed though your session (some features include statement number, and on multiple lines of input, which line you were on, as well as input/output indicators).

Are there any good (read: useful) alternatives to the default chevron I could look into, or is it worth my time?

<sub>also, if anyone's seen that link I mentioned, I'd appreciate it if you posted it as a comment...</sub>

Comment: This isn't the link I found, but it very similar: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/interpreter.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the default chevron to whatever you want and find what works best for you. Simply set `sys.ps1` to different values and play with it, you can also set `sys.ps2` to change the `...` take a look at this question: [Automatically execute commands on launching python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587709/automatically-execute-commands-on-launching-python-shell) to see how to set those automatically.

Comment: I never knew about this, very cool!  Trying to figure out now if I like `sys.ps1 = sys.ps2 = ''`...

Comment: @F.J and this whole time I thought *adding* to the prompt would be useful. Getting it out of the way is nice too!

Comment: @Droogans - Yeah, my main irritation with the prompt is that it makes it difficult to copy code out of it, so it is really nice to have a way to toggle it off.